# Does the .size directive here do anything?

Tags: assembly, llvm, gnu-assembler, powerpc

I'm currently trying to cross-compile musl 1.1.18 on an x86-64 host for a powerpc64le target using LLVM 3.7.1. It's failing to compile on the file/code shown below with `error: unexpected token in '.end' directive`. **That's not my question.**

From [src/internal/powerpc64/syscall.s](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/powerpc64/syscall.s?h=v1.1.18):

```
    .global __syscall
    .hidden __syscall
    .type   __syscall,@function
__syscall:
    mr      0, 3                  # Save the system call number
    mr      3, 4                  # Shift the arguments: arg1
    mr      4, 5                  # arg2
    mr      5, 6                  # arg3
    mr      6, 7                  # arg4
    mr      7, 8                  # arg5
    mr      8, 9                  # arg6
    sc
    bnslr+       # return if not summary overflow
    neg     3, 3 # otherwise error: return negated value.
    blr
    .end    __syscall
    .size   __syscall, .-__syscall
```

My question is: does the `.size` directive here do *anything*? [According to the gas documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.31/as/End.html), the `.end` directive signifies the end of the file and nothing further will be processed. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an undocumented feature of the GNU assembler. Apparently it is used to emit debug information in ECOFF format. See [gas/config/obj-ecoff.c:259](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/config/obj-ecoff.c;h=4bc3ded723aa5fd68f67ad29340334f70a286b2e;hb=HEAD#l259)
and [gas/ecoff.c:2981](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/ecoff.c;h=6b05026decab90646f8e250c47bfbcb7ebd7c769;hb=HEAD#l2981)

```c
/* ECOFF specific debugging information.  */
{ "aent",     ecoff_directive_ent,    1 },
{ "begin",    ecoff_directive_begin,  0 },
{ "bend",     ecoff_directive_bend,   0 },
{ "end",      ecoff_directive_end,    0 },
```

Comment: Intriguing! So assuming I'm not using ECOFF format, deleting the `.end` directive likely won't cause any harm, correct?

Comment: Even if you were, I'd say it would just cost you the ability to see a function's extent and that only if your debugger can't process the metadata emitted by the `.size`.